# bashdb startup error: bashdb/lib/setshow.sh: line 91: /dev/pts/2: Permission denied

Tags: linux, bash, shell, debugging, trepan

I'm trying to use bashdb on CentOS 4.1 (unfortunately I can't choose a different/newer OS). 
I installed bash 4.2 then bashdb 4.2-0.8. THere were no complaints from configure, make, make checks, or make install: everything looked peachy.

But trying to use bashdb either as 'bash --debugger myscript' or 'bashdb myscript' always gets this error:

```
[bot@sjbld1 bin]$ bashdb --  putxen.sh
bash debugger, bashdb, release 4.2-0.8

Copyright 2002, 2003, 2004, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011 Rocky Bernstein
This is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.

/usr/local/share/bashdb/lib/setshow.sh: line 91: /dev/pts/2: Permission denied
/usr/local/share/bashdb/lib/setshow.sh: line 91: /dev/pts/2: Permission denied
/usr/local/share/bashdb/lib/setshow.sh: line 91: /dev/pts/2: Permission denied
/usr/local/share/bashdb/lib/setshow.sh: line 91: /dev/pts/2: Permission denied
[bot@sjbld1 bin]$
```

There's no line 91 in setshow.sh, and there's no /dev/pts in a directory listing of /dev.

Any suggestions how to proceed will be very much appreciated.  I'm  taking on a broken mess of shell script, and I'm not hot at bash (or Linux) and hope for more intimate debugging than set -x and echo statements.

Thanks

For completeness I should have added the bash script I was trying to use as bashdb test,  as requested by konsolebox, though the "Permission denied" problem occurs with any code, and is solved by using sudo as suggested by Red Cricket. Here's the script:

```
[bot@sjcpbrvpxbld1 bin]$ cat putxen.sh
if [ x$1 == x ]
then
    echo must have filename as parameter
    exit 1
fi
if [ -e $1 ]
then
    echo $1 found
else
    echo cannot find ./$1
    exit 1
fi
FTPTGT=10.10.10.25
DIRTGT=xva
echo ftp upload file to $DIRTGT directory on $FTPTGT
ftp -n $FTPTGT <<EOF
user anonymous pass
hash
bin
cd $DIRTGT
put "$1"
bye
```

Comment: Please show your code or a crucial part of it that makes the error show.

Comment: try `sudo ...` and see what happens

Comment: YAY! Thanks Red Cricket (and duh, me): with sudo bashdb is working fine :-)  Many thanks, that's a huge help for me.

Comment: @Alan would you post this as an answer so this can be accepted and closed?

Comment: @rocky _would you post this as an answer_   I'd be happy to but how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since programs often have stdout and stderr redirected, bashdb tries to write its output to a tty, unless directed otherwise; *bashdb* determines the console running the `tty` command.

Normally you don't need to run *bashdb* as root. But for reasons that are a mystery here, the user you are running *bashdb* as, is not able to write to the tty registered to it. That is:

```
 echo hi > $(tty)
```

will probably give you the same "Permission denied". Probably `ls -l $(tty)` will tell you what's up there.

However, as suggested in the comments, you can workaround this by running as root such as via sudo: e.g.

```
sudo bashdb --  putxen.sh
```

Another workaround is to add your user to the group, e.g. *tty* that is listed when you run `ls -l $(tty)`.

Comment: thanks Rocky, marked as the answer (as Red Cricket's comment isn't markable)